# how to load from file to dynamic array of structures C

Tags: c

I am having an issue with loading from file to dynamic array of structures.Structure data are divided by blank line. I am having problems when using fgets() with numbers. Any suggestions?

```
for(i = 0 ; i < numOf structs ; i++)
  {
    fgets((arrayOfStructs + i)->name,50,file);
    fgets(&(arrayOfStructs + i)->gender,2,file);
    fscanf(file,"%d",&(arrayOfStructs + i)->year);
    fscanf(file,"%s",&(arrayOfStructs+ i)->id);
    fscanf(file,"%d",&(arrayOfStructs + i)->type);
    fscanf(file,"%d",&(arrayOfStructs + i)->fee);
    fscanf(file,"%d",&(arrayOfStructs + i)->date);
    fscanf(file,"%s",(arrayOfStructs + i)->space);//i don't know how to go trough the blank line correctly

  }
file example:
John Doe
Z
1995
GH121YT
0
10
20170815

John Doe2
M
1986
AS234SA
0
1800
20180613

John Doe3
M
1982
YU354SC
1
540
20181024
```

Comment: What is the definition of `arrayOfStructs`? Have you allocated memory for `name` and `gender`?

Comment: typedef struct {
        char name[50];
        char gender;
        int year;
        char id[8];
        int type;
        int fee;
        int date;
        char space[2];
}list;